# Sum $\cos x + \cos 2x + \cdots + \cos (n-1)x.$

Tags: sequences-and-series, trigonometry, summation

Find the sum of the series $$\cos x + \cos 2x + \cdots + \cos (n-1)x.$$
You must calculate the sum of this series **only** by multiplying through by $2\sin\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)$.

Now I've heard of finding the sum of a trig series by finding real and imaginary parts etc., but I have *no* idea how to do it this way.

Comment: Hint: $\cos(ax) \sin(x/2) = \dfrac{\sin((a+1/2)x) - \sin((a-1/2)x)}{2}$

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From the familiar identitiea
$$\sin(A+B)=\sin A\cos B+\cos A\sin B$$
and 
$$\sin(A-B)=\sin A\cos B-\cos A\sin B$$
we obtain
$$2\cos A\sin B=\sin(A+B)-\sin(A-B).$$
Set $B=\sin(x/2)$ and $A=\cos(kx)$. We get 
$$2\cos(kx)\sin(x/2)=\sin((k+1/2)x)-\sin((k-1/2)x).$$
Add up, $k=1$ to $k=n-1$. There is a lot of cancellation (telescoping) on the right. The only surviving part is $\sin((n-1/2)x)-\sin(x/2)$.

**Remark:** The method doesn't quite work if $\sin(x/2)=0$, but then finding the sum of the cosines is easy. The closed-form formula is "almost" right even for these $x$, in the sense that it has the right limit.

A similar trick, using the addition law for cosine, gives a closed-form expression for $\sin x+\sin 2x+\cdots+\sin((n-1)x$.

Comment: Hi andre thank you :)

would the limits for the sigma notation for this series be k=1 and n? could i go from there?